# How do I back up network and printer settings?

Tags: wireless, networking, printing, backup

Network and printer settings are not stored in users' /home directories and so will be overwritten by a fresh install of Ubuntu.

How can I back up those settings to ensure that I do not lose my current setup for wireless networks and printers?

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 but I imagine this is something that can be answered generically for all Ubuntu versions.

Comment: For printing, this blog post recommends to copy `/etc/cups` folder: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-migrate-printer-configuration.html.

Answer (score 6):

Taken from [Ubuntu man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/printers.conf.5.html)

> The  printers.conf  file defines the local printers that are available.
>          It is normally located in the  /etc/cups  directory  and  is  generated
>          automatically  by  the  cupsd(8)  program  when  printers  are added or
>          deleted.

`/etc/NetworkManager` is the directory where network settings are stored.

Knowing the above places you will be able to copy both settings files to a safe place. Keep in mind that settings files may or may not change in future releases of the Distro so it is wise to keep them as a guide and not paste them back blindly.

An example with all the steps and files involved in backing up 1 printer setup in Ubuntu 15.04

```
sudo service cups stop
sudo cp /etc/cups/printers.conf /etc/cups/printers.conf.bup
sudo cp my_backup/printers.conf /etc/cups
sudo cp my_backup/printers.conf.O /etc/cups
sudo cp /etc/cups/subscriptions.conf /etc/cups/subscriptions.conf.bup
sudo cp my_backup/subscriptions.conf /etc/cups
sudo cp my_backup/subscriptions.conf.O /etc/cups
sudo cp my_backup/ppd/Kyocera-FS-C5400DN-KPDL.ppd /etc/cups/ppd
sudo service cups start
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the valuable cautions.  With the printer config I found it better to save a copy of the file and manually re-enter the details using the "Add Printer" dialog -- just copying the file resulted in print jobs going wildly wrong.

Copy-pasting the network settings on the other hand seemed innocuous (at least transferring from 13.04 to 13.10).

Comment: Pleas consider to formulate an answer with your findings then so it can act as future reference for others with similar needs.

Comment: @WebDrake, just copying network settings to a different machine did not quite work for me because of settings such as `mac-address`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/706724.