# How do I backup my printer?

Tags: printing, 17.10

I want to do a fresh installation of Ubuntu but keep my installed printer so I don't have to do the process again of installing and configuring it.

How can I best back it up and restore it on the new installation?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this already?https://askubuntu.com/questions/334267/how-do-i-back-up-network-and-printer-settings

Comment: Thank you! So, essentially backing up `/etc/cups`. Filed a bug to request a user friendly feature [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790247).

Comment: I note that the person who asked the question; and carried out what was suggested commented "With the printer config I found it better to save a copy of the file and manually re-enter the details using the "Add Printer" dialog -- just copying the file resulted in print jobs going wildly wrong." and I guess I would say that since 17.04 there is airprint support for newish printers; so ubuntu auto-configures; and you seem to use a very generic printer driver; which printer do you have? Maybe you could access a better driver? .... so is advice on copying files is really sensible .......?

Comment: Hard to say for me. It's a network printer. See [this](https://imgur.com/a/IOZOK). So, in this case the best is hoping that they are going to implement a graphical way as mentioned in the bug report above?